# Download file and populate Grid in ASP.NET at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, grid

I try to use a **ASP.NET button** event to do two things are

1. Populate a Grid
2. Download/Export a file

The code I have got sends the file with correct data but

A. Grid is not populated

B. There is an exception `Response.End();`

Any clue how to fix it?

```
protected void ButtonExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       ... Getting startDate, endDate
       List<WorkOrder> result = GetWorkOders(startDate, endDate); // It populates Grid  using  GridViewWorkOrders.DataSource = result;             GridViewWorkOrders.DataBind();

       string csv = DataHelper.ToCsv(";", result);  

       var filename = "WorkOrders-ingresados-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy-HHmmsss");

       Response.Clear();

       Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".csv");
       Response.Write(csv);
       Response.End(); // The exception occurs here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE #1

I could get rid of the exception replacing `Response.End()` with

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
```

but anyway grid is not populated.

ANy clue if it is possible at all?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: show some related code from `GetWorkOders` method

Comment: @JAG Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: @VivekSharma It happening at ` Response.End();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. i think the the issue is

you are trying to send multiple `Content-Type` in single response which is not possible

1. to populate Grid, server need to send `html` so the `Content-Type: text/html`
2. to download a file `Content-Type: text/csv`

in your code you are overriding the `text/html` (which is default when `GridView.DataBind()` called) with `text/csv`

so the grid view html will be erased and csv content will be attached to response

**alternate**

first send GridView Bind response without the csv file

then once page loaded with new Grid, call a script function which calls a method in server to download csv file